# Is there a name for open-top curtains?

Tags: windows, blinds

I've walked around my neighborhood, and seen curtains that leave around the top 1/4 of the window open, which I really like. It seems to provide the same amount of privacy, but also let in a good amount of direct sunlight even if they're closed. I've tried searching for them in different places, but nothing really seems to come up. Are they just normal window shades/blinds installed lower? Are these a common design? Is there a name for them? Are there any drawbacks or hangups to doing them?

Comment: A neat solution when the window is longer than the curtain :)

Comment: Potential drawbacks: 1) Your neighbor's house has a 2nd floor window and they can see over the top of the curtain into a room where you're changing clothes. Of course, that's only a drawback if you have a hangup about being seen naked by strangers (or other non-spouse individuals). _Don't forget the neighbors a block away with binoculars!_ 2) If there's a streetlight that might shine over the top of the curtain into your bedroom, making it difficult for you to get to sleep at night. 3) Unblockable reflections off of TV or computer screens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to work for Lowes and I believe you’re referring to the cordless cellular shades that you can control from the top or bottom in order to maintain privacy and allow plenty of sunlight in as you mentioned, or you can put them all the way up from the bottom, and even play with color/ filter options. Not may drawbacks that I can remember. They are typically mounted inside the window frame, as long as your window allows for inside mount you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: Great start keep the answers coming , the photo really helped me I was thinking no top curtains+

Comment: This does answer the question (+1 from me), but that just looks so... wrong. Like "I just ordered these expense custom blinds and I spec'd them wrong so they're too short, but I spent so much on them I'm going to hang them anyway". No offense intended to OP who likes this style - that's just how it strikes me...

Comment: Nice answer. @FreeMan I guess it's a matter of preference.  If you've seen them installed or operated them you'd probably feel different. yhey are pretty neat.+